# Apache-Pulsar Throughput

Tags: node.js, throughput, apache-pulsar

I am running apache-pulsar standalone on my local machine as docker container for queuing system and pushing 1000 jobs to one topic (lets say 'demo').

If I have 1 consumer listening to 'demo' topic and processing the job and acknowledging (within 100ms - 500ms). All the jobs gets completed in around 80 secs.

But if I have do the same 1000 jobs test with more consumers (2 or 4 consumers), the overall throughput remains the same like around 80 secs.

I am not sure whether I am missing some configurations needed or will need multiple pulsar brokers or what should I do so that if I increase the consumers, consumption throughput should also gets increased (like around 40-45 secs incase of 2 consumers).

Docker image: apachepulsar/pulsar

consumer options:
"subscriptionType": "Shared",
"receiverQueueSize": 100,
"ackTimeoutMillis": 1200000

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are actually running multiple consumers?  Are they in multiple containers?  VMs? servers?   How many is each one receiving?

Are they consuming async or sync?

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-messaging/

What version of NodeJS?  What version of client?  What version of Pulsar?

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries-node/#consumers

Try to up the queue size to 1000

To get access to all the Pulsar people in one location, sign up for the summit.

https://streamnative.io/en/blog/community/2021-09-07-speakers-announced-for-pulsar-virtual-summit-europe-2021/

Answer (score -1):

There can be multiple consumer as long as the consumer has no restriction.
A Consumer can get the required cert files from the producer and the consumers can name the subscription name. and can check which consumers are actually connected.